# Get child type in abstract class constructor

Tags: typescript, abstract-class, typescript-generics

I have an abstract class that will take any data passed into the constructor and assign it to the instance. The goal being that you can initialize an instance with a subset of its data.

The problem I'm having is that the once the abstract class has been extended, the child class constructor expects an argument of type `Partial<AbstractParent>` instead of `Partial<Child>`.

I've been able to mimic this pattern with a static create method, generics, and usage of the `this` param, but I would much prefer if I was able to do this with the constructor.

[Minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4HsCuUkDCWIGYUOCYWUyA3gFDLIgQDuAFACZxhwBcyAApwoYYHAA2AHnTY8SAHwBKAbNz4I9RsgRQIPCFIAqyCAA9IIThjSZ1hYqXKVqC9mAAWwDAKMAaZG5eAWFRcWkASRJeECQjAE8AB0MjBWUBKNI4WIgE5OMFAG56AF8tOAAjJ0QwHQk4DBs1eRQGJkScColgBGRK6spkYE4BEBwAWwroYu0ERzIKKiguHn4hETFJGTsW5TptJgB5CoArCEoAOgaMYABzEHcvDACguCVipjLtLLFe3X1IMZTBYIFYmjsNERos4lm5PN5fC9ViENuEpJkYnEkik0ipkBjslj8ql9kwmHNokNooSUABeZhsZDwjArXhKPo2Ak5PI4j5kvRgPAgKlZHJ8spfBD1RrIACy8WaGmBlmstjkSraQxGzAmUxo9IAjHzsOMIAAxYAQCTapygW7IekAcgAbpIcBBHcVJfNkOMFRCkA6Gaw5f71Uh2LRkCbzZbrQJHR4rRIsMhWNRrY7kCV3loKaQ+iAsJ5oIrA-T5WWIBd-gZI9GsKaLVbtYnk6n01BM9n3kA)

```js
interface ResourceConstructor {
  new(data: Partial<Resource>): Resource

  create<T extends ResourceConstructor>(this: T, data: Partial<InstanceType<T>>): InstanceType<T>;
}

abstract class Resource {
  public abstract id: number;

  constructor(data: Partial<Resource>) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  static create<T extends ResourceConstructor>(this: T, data: Partial<InstanceType<T>>): InstanceType<T> {
    const instance = new this(data) as InstanceType<T>;
    return instance;
  }
}

class MyResource extends Resource {
  id: number = 1;
  someField: string = 'value';
}

const myResource = new MyResource({ someField: 'hello world' }); 
//this produces an error "Argument of type '{ someField: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Resource>'"

const anotherResource = MyResource.create({ someField: 'hello world' });
```

Comment: This is a missing feature of TS, described at [ms/TS#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) and more specifically at [ms/TS#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038).  So there's no "direct" way to do it, only workarounds, such as the static generic create function you're already using.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz This is spot on; thank you! The idea of a "polymorphic this" is exactly what I was trying to describe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually you'd like the constructor to accept a parameter of type `Partial<this>`, using the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types).  Unfortunately, you cannot currently use polymorphic `this` in parameter types for the static side of a class, which includes the `constructor` method.  There are longstanding open feature requests for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#5863](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863) and more specifically at [microsoft/TypeScript#38038](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38038).  Until and unless these get implemented, you can't express what you want directly.

For now, you'd need to just work around it.  One popular workaround, as mentioned in those issues, is to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) static method with a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters).  Of course this means you'd need to use `Ctor.create()` instead of `new Ctor()`.  I'd explain how to do it, except that you've already found this workaround and implemented it in your example code.  Oh well, I'm afraid there's nothing particularly better than this at the moment.